# Where to Find "Practical Nonparametric Statistics" by W.J. Conover?

Tags: reference-request

I am taking a course on non-parametric statistics in my final year of my undergrad this fall, and our professor told us to get the book "Practical Nonparametric Statistics" by W.J. Conover. I can't seem to find a hard-copy at any bookstore I've gone to so far (my university bookstore, Chapters, etc.); is there any free pdf version online, or alternatively is amazon my best bet for it? For some reason most math books are available online but this one in general seems obscure, both hard copy and online versions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On searching the title of the book on Google, I quickly found a softcopy edition of this book. I'm giving the required [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://140.117.153.69/ctdr/files/857_1734.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi-xJOt0sHkAhVGOI8KHR8fDSYQFjAMegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0BmfiC6E9Y3-Ur25icT7Ce&cshid=1567960055552).

Or if you prefer a physical copy of the book, I would recommend you to use [Bookfinder](https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?ac=sl&st=sl&ref=bf_s2_a1_t1_1&qi=7g.0UDh1Z8GTPdPNUSmz1WBoAn4_1497963026_1:10:8&bq=author%3Dw%2E%2520j%2E%2520conover%26title%3Dpractical%2520nonparametric%2520statistics). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I went to the required link (for the softcopy) but it doesn't give all the pages; I'll use this for now and also ask my prof if I'm stuck just trying to get a copy from Amazon.